# How to get MAX int but exclude specific int?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, tsqlt

I'd like to get the max integer from a specific column excluding a value that will always be the max if present.  Data may look like the following:

```
score, empid
 1       3
 3       3
 10      3
 1       5 
 2       5
 1       8
 2       8
 3       8
 10      8
```

In the above, I'd like MAX score less than 10.  MAX(score) doesn't work in this case since it will bring back 10.  Results should look like this:

```
score, empid
 3       3
 2       5
 3       8
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select max(score) , empid
from table
where score < (select max(score) from table )
group by empid
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's an alternative method:

```
SELECT
   MAX(CASE WHEN score = 10 THEN NULL ELSE score END) AS [max_score],
   empid
FROM
   table
GROUP BY
   empid
```

This may be preferable if you prefer to avoid the sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

Following Ben English's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10111879/4212710), if you are excluding only 1 value, you can also use NULLIF for less typing.

```
SELECT MAX(NULLIF(score, 10)), ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
```

With `CASE WHEN` it's possible to exclude a range of values. Here we exclude all scores more than 10:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN score > 10 THEN NULL ELSE score), ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
```

And here is the `IIF` version for less typing:

```
SELECT MAX(IIF(score > 10, NULL, score)), ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
```